# Would a 'smallish' oracle for an NP complete problem actually be useful?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-complete, oracle-machines

A quick thought experiment here:

Suppose one could construct an oracle that could yield a solution to an NP-complete problem (3SAT, TSP, SUBSET, etc) for smallish (30-60) inputs in a single operation.

Would there be areas in computer science/graphics/processing/etc where this would be particularly useful?  Which NP complete problem would be the 'most useful' to have an oracle for?

Comment: It's easy to see that any such oracle can not change any $O$-complexities as you can not save more than a constant factor. So at least in complexity theore, such oracles are utterly boring. In more practical areas, assuming unit cost for an oracle is unlikely to be a good model for ... anything.

Comment: Just for a bit more clarity - this oracle would not have a fixed input size - but smallish number of inputs.  The size of those inputs could be huge.

Comment: Finite is finite.